# Convert value to absolute from field

Tags: php, html, absolute-value

I have a field that takes case id (negative value) to evaluate the conditions.

```
var cont =  $('<div></div>').insertAfter(condfld).css('margin-top', '5px');
var caseidfld = $('<input id=test_caseid type=text placeholder="test caseid"></input>').appendTo(cont);
```

In **case.id.field**, I would like for the user to input the value positive value, and system will compare it with data in the database (the case id value in the database is negative). I have a clue on how to do it, using abs(), but not sure how to do it properly...

Answer (score 0):

Try `Math.abs(caseidfld)` to get the absolute value. Multiply by -1 to make it negative, to compare with DB value.